# How do i check first character of input is zero (0) in php using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have form and one textbox. My expected output will accept only that input who has input starting with zero(0). And it should be all digits. There are no condition for many numbers. You can input many digits without any rules. It is very easy using java-script but i need in php.

Expected Output : 01252, 0989562232, 054543112,012

Not allowed : 12315, 215646, 2015

Comment: (^0\d+$) should do it

Answer (score 2):

The regex `#^0+\d*#` should do the trick. At least one `0`, then any digit.

```
<?php
if (preg_match("#^0+\d*#", $var))
{
    echo 'OK';
}
else
{
    echo 'NOK';
}
?>
```